# Access teamCity Build number in Java

Tags: java, teamcity

I am running my automation test suite from TeamCity. I need to access the buildId property as I have a situation where I have to construct a file path using this buildId.

I tried using System.getProperty("teamcity.build.id")  but it just displays null.  How can I access the buildID of the current team city run from my automation code which is written in java.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass it while running the build step, using %build.number%.

https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD5/Predefined+Properties